# Cannot create projects in brand new azure devops org

Tags: azure-devops

I showed a friend azure devops and she wanted to try it out. She created a brand new org, but cannot create any projects under the org. She gets a blank error at the top of the screen. It doesn't matter if any of the fields are filled out or not. Create is grayed out. (See below).

She is the org owner, has a basic license, is in the project collection admin group, and we verified she has create project permission. What is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was because my friend used an organization email to sign up for AzDO. Her org needs to grant O365 access. I've signed up with my personal email and didn't run into this issue.